Data Types and modifiers in C programming
Are data type modifiers considered independent data types? For example, is "long" a data type or are modifier?

const and volatile are "modifiers" (proper term is qualifiers). long is a type, long int is a type, long long int is a type. Despite syntax, you are not "adding" longs to a type, you are not modifying type by adding long, the type name itself contains a space.

One should take into account that C is one of the dinosaurs of not so well designed languages (that now are well specified). So the notions and terminology are a bit raw. Just as long and long int there is unsigned and unsigned int for instance.

Except that even 1000 years ago you could avoid such random naming convention. "We won't allow space in type names except for long long int, etc". Great idea, indeed.

@freakish I feel like the original idea was that types are modified by keywords - you add unsigned or signed to change signedness, you add long or short to change size, but by the time C was standardized they decided it's a horrible idea (because it is) and forced all the options into specific set of typenames.

There's no formal term called "modifier" in C so therefore nothing in C is a modifier.

The idea was never to allow general construction of types by combining keywords,  @Yksisarvinen. It was more pragmatic than that. The hardware to which early C was being ported provided for larger numbers of distinct native (integer) data types, and a way was needed to express those types in C. That led to long int and short int being introduced.  But C of that day allowed implicit int declarations, and long and short were (then) unambiguous without the int part, so it seemed natural to allow the int to be omitted.  The unsigned types came a bit later, but followed similar logic.

The rules in the C standard do not say the int keyword is directly a type and short or unsigned modify it to be a different type. Rather, there are rules about what type results from various combinations of keywords in a declaration. Primarily, an explicit list says what the combinations are.
The keywords we might think of as types, like int and float, and others we might think of as modifiers, like signed or long, are all type-specifier tokens in the C grammar, and they are not independent things that can be mixed and matched freely. In clause 6.7.3.1, the C 2024 standard gives a list of what combinations can be used in a declaration-specifiers list, including:

void
char
signed char
unsigned char
short, signed short, short int, or signed short int
…
unsigned long, or unsigned long int

and so on. The resulting types are discussed earlier, in 6.2.5. So the rules about what combinations of type specifiers mean what types are not a set of rules like “adding short modifies a type to be shorter” and such but are largely the result of explicit lists in 6.2.5 and elsewhere, such as a statement that the standard signed integer types are signed char, short int, int, long int, and long long int.
6.7.3.1 also says that any of the items listed on the same line in its list, such as short int and signed short int, are the same type, and the type specifiers can appear in any order in the declaration specifiers, possibly intermixed with other kinds of declaration specifiers, like int const short.

Interesting attribute about sign-ness of int vs signed int in bit fields - which may differ may apply here.
